# Regain control of an Apple Account

Tags: security, apple-id

I have an older Apple account i haven't used for a few years, I know the email (And have access to the email address) its linked to and i know the password.

However when i go to the apple account management page (https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) and tried to sign in, it asks for answers to my security questions which I know longer know the answers to. I tried to go to https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid but... it asks me for the answer to my security questions... when i select i need to change my security questions.

How can I go about regain control over this app?

Answer (score 1):

First thing - think twice before trying to brute force guess passwords. If this is due to a developer program requirement, and especially if you continue to pay for that - start with developer support.

It's OK that you forgot the passwords and ask what method you can take to validate it's really you regaining control of the account.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/

If you're locked out, you might need to make careful notes of what you click at:

- https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid

Be very clear what step you can't get past and be patient with the people helping. They are there to prevent someone wishing to take over your developer account so you might need to write a certified letter, get something notarized, take several weeks to get them to help.

When you're ready to admit you can't get in - phone support might be your last avenue to get someone to point you to any alternate unlock methods or deliver the news that Apple will not help you break into the account. If that’s the ultimate situation you would have to walk away from it since you can't verify you produced the answers they asked back when you initially secured the account.

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Comment: According to the OP, they know the password :-)

Comment: Yes - and knowing the password generally lets one generate a support PIN to indicate to Apple Support that you wish to grant them access to the account for purposes of resetting some data. Let’s hope that all works for them @nohillside